# How to assign value in a variable inside tf.while_loop body which was passed through loop_vars?

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
calrawstate=tf.while_loop(cond,body,[rawstate,x,v,coef])
```

Here `rawstate` and `v` are two variables created using `tf.get_variable()`
Now,

```
def body(rawstate,x,v,coef):
    rawstate.assign_add(tf.matmul(x[v],coef[v]))
    v.assign_add(1)
    return [rawstate,x,v,coef]
```

If I try to do something like this, It throws an exception,

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign_add'
```

Then how to assign value inside `tf.while_loop()` body?

Comment: Have you checked : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11311

Comment: Did you try using tf.assign_add?

Comment: @amirbar
def body(rawstate,x,v,coef):   
    tf.assign_add(rawstate,tf.matmul(x[v],coef[v]))   
    tf.assign_add(v,1)   
    return [rawstate,x,v,coef]   
this is throwing "TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'begin' has DataType float32 not in list of allowed values: int32, int64"

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul   
I don't think that is the issue